# Limits of a human with enhanced brain

Tags: trans-humanism

Some kind of computer chip has been implanted into the brain of one of my characters. Since then, he is able to willingly activate the chip for a short amount of time (between 5 and 10 minutes before reverting to his normal state).

As long as the chip is activated, my character is granted an incredible intellect and a nearly perfect mastery of his body.

Given the fact that this guy can perceive many more events and details than your average human in a shorter time lapse, and that he has a nearly perfect knowledge and mastery of his own body, what would be his limitations in terms of speed, strength, reflexes ?

edit : His chip allows him to perceive details that an average human would not see or at least notice (micro expressions) and compute things with a precision far beyond that of a human (the trajectory of a double pendulum can be an example of what he could compute).

About his knowledge and mastery of his body, what I mean is that he can feel very precisely every tensed muscle in his body or the state of every one of his organs. His mastery allows him to stay perfectly still for example, and control almost every muscle of his body.

Comment: One question per question, please. First question is kinda broad because we don't know if, and how, you want his senses to be enchanted, and what level of prediction you aim for. i can predict short term future. I can do it good enough to catch a glass before it hits the floor when I see it shaking on the edge of my table and I *feel* it'll fall. Almost any kid can predict trajectory of a ball good enough to catch it, et cetera. For second question: perfect knowledge? My gf is MD, she has knowledge of a human body far greater than mine, I don't see any difference in everyday life. Mastery?..

Comment: "*given the fact that he perceives and computes many more events than a regular human*"  He's not going to perceive the supersonic asteroid hurtling down, about to kill his sister.  And he's not going to perceive anything beyond his "five" senses.

Comment: He's not perceiving anything beyond his five senses indeed but he can pay attention a lot more details in a shorter time lapse than any other human

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/John_Doe_(TV_series)

Comment: Are you looking for the physical limits of what the human body could do, given that the brain could process all of the information it is given nearly instantly? In that case, You could look into muscle reaction times. If complete control over every muscle is attained, synchronisation of muscle groups could increase the character's strength despite having the same muscle mass. Reaction times would be limited to how fast the body could move, and short-time prediction would allow these near-instant reactions to interact with events before other people even realise that the event is happening.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I would like to answer your questions. But beware, it might be a longish read.

## 1 - Mental Abilities and Future Prediction

Our minds are always in a state of making future predictions and preparing our appropriate plans to react accordingly. One's ability to accurately predict the future depends on 2 things:

- availability of all related information
- deduction and induction skills to process this information

Your chip provides an enhancement to the first of these two, enabling the user to access very large amounts of data in an almost instantaneous way.

But what about the mental skills required to *process* this data? The skill to make inferences, implications and decisions? If the person is weak in these skills, larger amount of data will only serve to make him/her confused and undecided, instead of enhancing his intellect.

So, all in all, the chip will simply multiply the difference between this person's intellect and the common man's intellect; as in, it will make a smarter person far more smarter and an indecisive, mentally weak person, weaker and more indecisive. The extent of the difference will depend on the person's normal intellectual level.

Of course in cases where decision making is extremely linear and simple, the chip will grant the person almost magical skills.

## 2 - Physical Skills

If the chip enables the person to summon all of their muscles' power in an instant (a feat which only dedicated sportsmen can achieve), it will have obvious advantages for the user.

Can the chip control hormonal secretions and grant absolute emotional control? The user will become all the more psychologically strong and unbeatable.

Can the chip trigger permanent bodily changes (such as muscle growth, change of bone density and bone shape etc.)? It will make the person nearly a superman.

## 3 - Sample Scenarios

Note that I have assumed that the person using the chip has had an average IQ (without using the chip) of 105 and has a non-athletic, physically fit physique.

**1- The User is Playing is Participating in a Live Reality Show**

The person will be able to answer all trivia questions and win big $$$.

**2- The User is a Detective Working on a Case**

The officer will be able to instantly call data from a lot of police databases, compare patterns and narrow down the suspects far quicker than he would usually be able to. However, *whom* the officer charges as guilty slightly depends on his personality, too.

**3- The User is in a Prison Cell**

The user will be able to control his emotions and avoid getting pessimistic or depressed. He would be able to release endorphins in his brain whenever he pleases, in order to lift his mood and feel good about himself/herself even in apparently worst situations.

Comment: #3 is huge disadvantage, risk the rat with a wire in its brain scenario,way worse addictive properties than any drug. Makes heroin look like breath mints.

Comment: I disagree that they would be able to win a game show - just because they can think faster doesn't mean that they can suddenly remember things they never knew.